# Best way to update state

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vuex, state-management

In my application's state, I have a teacher's list, which is never empty. That piece of state, is used in two different views, **that the user can go directly** (they don't have to go to page1 and then to page 2, they can go directly to page 2 if they want to, or they can go to both). So my question is **¿How should I set the state? (I'm using vuex)**

So far, I've came across 2 solutions, but I don't think they are the best ones:

1. Set the state every time I need to access the property. (maybe with a getter and doing something like `if(store.getters.teachers.length < 1) await dispatch('SET_TEACHERS')`)
2. Having that logic in the action `SET_TEACHERS() { if(state.teachers.length < 1) //Api call }`

I don't like the first one because the data won't change that often, and the second might be OK, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar situation right now. My vuex state should be available in N views/components and fetching data whenever a component is mounted is a waste of resources. Besides that, you will lose the most important vuex usability by coupling your vuex store with your components.

I recommend you to decouple your vuex from your views by hydrating your state out from any child component (IE your App.vue) and just mapping your state in children components.

You may wonder then how to update your state if anything changes. Well, this is the tricky part. If you are working with your own API Rest you can emit a WebSocket event. Then, you can listen to that event and dispatch your SET_TEACHERS as per the payload received from API.

Believe me, I'm just an amateur with WebSockets but it's saving me a ton of time and the user experience is awesome.

Hope it helps to give you a different point of view on your situation.

Comment: I got it! The problem is that I'm using Nuxt, and it doesn't have such file. Anyways, after searching a little bit more, I came to the conclusion that using  mixin where I do the validation  if the array is empty, could be a good solution. The data won't change that often, so maybe using websockets is a little bit overkilled. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your main issue. Go for mixins if you just need a "global" function to accomplish DRY. Then you just could call that mixin function and set the returned response in your local data component. 

I would consider if you really need vuex before moving forward: "Do you really need to keep your data through the whole lifecycle of your app", "Does it make sense to maintain a vuex store just for DRY code?".

Be careful about using vuex for something that doesn't really need it. The main purpose of vuex is to maintain independence between views and states.

Comment: That's true! I think that I'd need Vuex if in a view the user could edit the teachers, or delete them, but that's not the case (only logged in users can do that). So with a mixin I should be fine I guess. The problem with that is that the API response wont be cache, so every time the user navigates to another page and goes back to the previous one, it'll have to refetch the teachers' list. Anyways, for this last problem I could use `keep-alive` https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/with-keep-alive (the data wont change that often). Gracias maestro!